# Overriding core JS commands?

Tags: javascript, browser

I'm trying to modify/limit/prevent access to certain JS commands of my browser. For example commands like `navigator.clipboard`; However, I'm not sure how to approach this.

Is it possible to override these commands with user-defined javascript injected in the page, or do i have to edit the browser's javascript compiler and re-compile it from source for this?

I'm not really familiar with browsers and want to save time by knowing a general direction to follow. Thanks

Comment: Are you coming at this from the angle of a user of the browser wanting to stop pages you visit doing these things, or from the owner of a page where you want to stop your users doing these things?

Comment: `navigator` is not a part of JS, it's a DOM API.

Comment: Whichever of these solutions you try, they will make you unhappy. Monkey-patching your browser's global JS objects can lead to unexpected effects and is not guaranteed to ever work after a browser update. Compiling your own JavaScript engine will lead you to having to maintain a full browser branch including updates, security patches, ... What is it that you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to create a something like a customizable "NoScript" extension that allows me to edit JS outputs instead of blocking them altogether. Sorry for not clarifying

Answer (score 1):

First of all `navigator.clipboard` is not a function, but here is an example using the `read` function of `navigator.clipboard`:

```
navigator.clipboard.read = function (originalFunction) {
    return function (yourParamsYouWantForThisFunction) {
        // Do Stuff you wanna do before the real call. For example:
        console.log(yourParamsYouWantForThisFunction);

        // Call the original function
        return originalFunction.call();
    };
}(navigator.clipboard.read); // Pass the original function reference as a parameter
```

You may wonder, why there are two `function` statements:

- The first one is there, so that we can pass the original function at runtime. If we would not do that, we would not be able to access the original `navigator.clipboard.read` function.
- The second function is the actual function, that you will be using later, when you call `navigator.clipboard.read()`.